# How do I defeat the knights in candy box 2? They always kill me

Tags: candy-box-2

I have the octopus kings crown and the monkey wizards staff and pink enchanted gloves with 423 health.

Comment: Did you enchant the Octopus King's crown?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get past the Knights is to obtain an item called the [Magic Sponge](https://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Magical_sponge).  The sponge can be found in the Sea, but you will need to keep an eye on the seabed and grab it as you pass by.  I noticed it around the eels, but I'm not sure if it can spawn earlier.

Once you have it, you can shrink, allowing you to walk right under the knights.